# Backbone Model .changedAttributes() not showing all changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My abbreviated model looks like this:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({
  defaults: {
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    constrain_proportions: true
  },
  initialize: function () {
    // Do stuff to calculate the aspect ratio of x and y
    this.on('change:x', doStuff, this);
    this.on('change:y', doStuff, this);
  },
  doStuff: function () {
    // ...
    if (this.get('constrain_proportions')) {
      var changes = this.changedAttributes();
      // Do stuff to make sure proportions are constrained
    }
  }
});
```

I am running into an issue where I am making a change like so:

```
model.set({
  x: 50,
  y: 60
});
```

In my `doStuff` method I want to make sure that when `constrain_proportions` is set to true, changing one attribute, will change the other one, keeping the same aspect ratio. When I update `x` and `y` together, the aspect ratio changes. The problem I'm running into is that when you make a change on a Backbone Model using the code above, the `x` attribute is the same as the default value. In Backbone, this causes `model.changedAttributes()` to return:

```
{ y: 60 }
```

Which is due to this chunk of code in the `Model.set` method:

```
// For each `set` attribute, update or delete the current value.
  for (attr in attrs) {
    val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
    if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val)) {
      this.changed[attr] = val;
    } else {
      delete this.changed[attr]; // The culprit is right here
    }
    unset ? delete current[attr] : current[attr] = val;
  }
```

Without knowing that the `x` value has changed to 50 in addition to the `y` value changing to 60, my code updates the `x` value to 60, so that it keeps with the aspect ratio of 1:1 set up by the initialization of model. By making the change of `{x: 50, y: 60}` I want to change the aspect ratio to 5:6 but the code above from Backbone keeps that from happening when value being changed is same as it was previously.

How do I successfully get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've wanted to force a change event I silently unset the attribute then set it again:

```
model.unset('x', { silent: true }).unset('y', { silent: true }).set({ x: 50, y: 60 });
```

To make it more convenient you could wrap it in another function on the model:

```
setXY: function(x, y) {
    this.unset('x', { silent: true }).unset('y', { silent: true }).set({ x: x, y: y });
}
```